# Rendering Sliced images using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been given the task of rendering sliced images using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

My teacher has supplied me with a folder of sliced images. I have been asked to place each image into a table `<td>` individually. There are 4 rows and 5 columns per row (20 sliced images). I now need to use [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to render the images, creating an whole image with no blank spaces or gaps in between the slices.

My teacher has given me a clue in that I need to use a nested for loop to render the slices together and that the rendering should be achieved by a single statement.

I understand nested for loops, but I cannot seem to wrap my head this task. Can someone please show me how to render sliced images within a table, using a single nested for loop statement, leaving no gaps or blank spaces?

```
//JavaScript

var numRows = 4;
var numCols = 5;

var redBowl = document.getElementsByClassName('orderImage');
  var orderImage = '';

for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    orderImage += '<tr>';
        for(var j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
            orderImage += '<td>' + i + j + '</td>'; 
    }
orderImage += '</tr>';
}

redBowl.innerHTML = orderImage;

//HTML 

<table class="orderImage">

<tr>

<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r1_c1.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>

<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r1_c2.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r1_c3.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r1_c4.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
    alt="Red bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r1_c5.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
    alt="Red bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>

</tr>

<tr> 

<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r2_c1.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
    alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r2_c2.jpg" width="130" height="80 
    alt="Red 
     Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r2_c3.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
    alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r2_c4.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
    alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r2_c5.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
    alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>

</tr> 


<tr> 

<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r3_c1.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r3_c2.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r3_c3.jpg" width="130" height="80 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r3_c4.jpg" width="130" height="80 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r3_c5.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r4_c1.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r4_c2.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r4_c3.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r4_c4.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>
<td><img src="images/bcpot002_r4_c5.jpg" width="130" height="80" 
     alt="Red Bowl" title="Red Bowl"/></td>

</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Can you please show some of your efforts which you have done so far before asking question here.. ?

Comment: Yeah, Please show us what you tried!

Comment: I have typed out my Javascript statement very similar to Dario's example below and have typed out a table in my HTML document sourcing all of the necessary image slices individually in their allocated TD's, however the image is not rendering as expected. There should not be any gaps or blank spaces in between the image slices, it should preview as a solid image.

Comment: I have edited my post so that can see the code.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple nested loop example. Is this help enough or what have you tried and where are you stuck?

```js
var ele = document.getElementById('table');
var table = '';

for(var i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
 table += '<tr>';
  for(var j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) {
   table += '<td>' + i + j + '</td>';
  }
  table += '</tr>';
}
ele.innerHTML = table;
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<table id="table"></table>
```